# Worldwide hotel search with filtering

Tags: accommodation-search-engines

I'm looking for a website that allows me to search for hotels across the world. Reason being that I have no clue where to go for vacation and I'd like to decide based on hotel availability / price / images. To reduce the number of hotels to look at I'd like to set filters like "close to a beach", "kitchen", etc...

momondo.com advertises such a feature but it only seems to be available for flights? https://www.momondo.com/discover/article/anywhere-search

airbnb.com allows you to search "anywhere", but then doesn't allow you to use filters. It's more like a best-of summary.

Comment: Having done such a search for just one country, then reduced to one area in it, I doubt you want to really do it world wide. And are you really that interested in comparing hotels in the same price class in countries where in one you are in the top half of the range and in the other in standard to low class hotels? (Like when you compare the Netherlands with Albania?)

Comment: There must be some factors you could use to narrow down your search. Don’t considerations such as weather, countries/places you’ve already visited, length of flight, entry requirements etc come into play at all? And **when** you want to /are able to travel? If you really don’t know where to go why not just stick a pin in a map and then do your hotel search based on that?

Comment: Fair points, thanks for your responses. I see why this is a bit more complicated than I thought now. Weather is very important of course (especially when searching for hotels "close to a beach"!). So maybe what I'm looking for is not a search engine for hotels per se, but "travel experiences" instead? You define weather, activities (i.e. beach) and timeframe - based on that the search engine tells me possible places to go. I assume such a thing doesn't exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a comment you said **maybe what I’m looking for is not a search engine for hotels per se, but ‘travel experiences’ instead**.

Searching ‘where should I go on vacation’ or similar throws up a raft of recommendation sites such as https://www.cntraveller.com/gallery/top-holiday-destinations-2019, including a few that let you input your trip criteria before displaying supposedly personalised recommendations. For example, http://www.tripzard.com/ asks a number of quite detailed questions, whereas http://travelpicker.com/ helps you identify possible destinations based on six basic criteria.

Comment: travelpicker.com looks great! I'll give those a try, thanks for your help.